# I have created branch from development, worked on it, now I want to merge this to master without merging development code

Tags: git, merge

It took me a while to create a proper and simple title for this question.

I was working on the development branch code and then I realized that the task I have completed will be pushed to master. The problem now is my branch contains development work as well, because I have created the branch from development.

I tried to search for this on the internet but maybe I could not find the proper search terms.

Please can anyone help me with merging my work to master directly without merging the development code, Thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your branch is called `my-branch`. You can use this one-liner to rewrite your branch as if you originally branched off of `master` instead of `development`:

```
git rebase development my-branch --onto master
```

In words, the above command says:

> Take all of the commits on `my-branch` that are not reachable by `development`, and replay them one by one, in order, onto `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to your `master` branch and `cherry-pick` your commits that you want to be in master. Don't forget to update your master branch by pulling before cherry-picking.

```
git commit // commit your work on the development branch
git log HEAD~n // to learn the commit id's.
                // Replace n with number of commits you want to see
git checkout master
git pull
// cherry-pick in the order from earliest to the latest
git cherry-pick <commit-id-1>
....
git cherry-pick <commit-id-n>
```

Comment: Great I will do it and update you.

Comment: @GhazniAli you may need to resolve conflicts during cherry-picking.

Comment: I will create a test and then will have a look how it works.

Comment: Thank you I tried another solution which I have marked as selected it worked.